# nodemon not updating the page after save

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, nodemon

I am trying to learn nodeJS and installed nodemon, and it seems to be installed, but it does not actually restart the server. But after that, when I make some changes to the page, it displays, but it does not actually reload the server (so I have to do it manually). How can I fix this problem, because it is properly installed, using `npm install -g nodemon`. If there is no way out of this problem, is there an alternative to nodemon? Here's my package.json:

```
{"dependencies": {"express": "^4.17.3","nodemon": "^2.0.15"}}
```

I tried installing nodemon locally, reinstalling visual studio code, deleting all nodeJS modules, deleting nodeJS, reinstalling nodemon globally

[Console output after first nodemon command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CBM2.png)

[Console output after all next nodemon commands (notice it is not restarting the server)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VubWQ.png)

Answer (score 3):

Could you show the package.json file? there is this script
like this on my case:

```
"scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
       "start": "nodemon app.js",
       "start-server": "node app.js"
  },
```

Try like that code. If that doesn't work try legacy watch mode and use this code:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon -L app.js",
    "start-server": "node app.js",
    
 }
```

Run command would be for the above code:

```
npm start
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: {"dependencies": {"express": "^4.17.3","nodemon": "^2.0.15"}}

Comment: That's the entire package.json

Comment: That's quite unusual. Have you tried npm init again?

Answer (score 0):

By chance, are you running nodemon from the same directory as app.js (or whatever file)? When I give nodemon a path and not simply a file like …

```
$ nodemon app.js
```

VS

```
$ nodemon server/app.js
```

The first will update, the second will not for me ever. There is probably some config change but defaults are all I use.

Answer (score -2):

I felt compelled to give another answer curtesy of ChatGPT. Turns out this could be a permissions problem. If you are accessing a project/files through Window's share the problem is probably with the permissions on the share itself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).